# Ability to automatically dim secondary monitor when focus on primary

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt-display

Is there a 3rd party app or combination of system settings and scripts that dims a secondary monitor until focus is brought to a window displayed on it? I like having multiple monitors but I would work better if there were a strong contrast between the two, where the contrast would invert based on which monitor had focus. (I can and do manually adjust the brightness when I know I won't need anything on the secondary monitor for awhile).

Running El Capitan with primary of a Thunderbolt display and secondary of a Macbook Pro.

I have looked at questions such as
[Show a screensaver on a secondary display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49602/is-it-possible-to-show-a-screensaver-on-a-secondary-monitor-while-using-the-prim) and
[Adjust brightness of secondary display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20237/can-i-change-the-brightness-on-a-secondary-display/121330#121330) and have a sense that some of the tools might, with a additional scripting, get me close to what I'm looking for, but I am hoping someone has already solved this specific issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but this very simple work around found here [Can I change the brightness on a secondary display?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28474/115373) should help me out a lot.

_If you press Control-F1 or Control-F2 the brightness on a secondary display will adjust._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using the free app [HazeOver](http://hazeover.com) which dims all windows other than the one with focus. The new beta version has a preference to dim all windows on a secondary monitor, and it gives me exactly the functionality I need. You can also opt to not dim windows that belong to the app in focus.  (I paid for it, which just removes messages encouraging you to purchase it).